# Jquery .prependTo() use for the tag

Tags: jquery, css

how to use prependTo to add class `<div class="table-responsive">` above tag table?

**I know how it works, but it is before the TABLE tag does not put the div with the class**

Comment: plz briefly what you want in question

Comment: I have no idea what is the question... Completly unclear imho. Provide minimalistic sample of what you are talking about. EDIT: I guess you want to prepend a DIV to a TABLE, but it result in invalid HTML markup so browser parse it as it can/wish ...

Comment: @Sumitpatel I haven't tag `div` with class `table-responsive`. Just i want to add this class before tag `table`, that table was within a class `table-responsive`

Comment: So it would be `$('<div class="table-responsive"/>').insertBefore('.table-responsive table');`. But you said `that table was within a class table-responsive`, that's still unclear if you have already the table inside other div with class `table-responsive` or not... Because how i understand it, it would result in two div with class `table-responsive` or this is the table with this class or what?!. A simple HTML markup of what you have and what you are expecting would make it clearer for sure...

Comment: Or you want to add class to the div which is previous element of the table. Damn, the more i read the question/comment, the less i understand it

Comment: And now i suppose the div wrap the table. It is funny how this question is unclear and how OP doesn't make any effort to explain it better...

Comment: @A.Wolff Don't panic maan... blonfu showed an example of exactly what I want

Comment: Glad you have find your answer. So `but it is before the TABLE tag does not put the div with the class` means `How to wrap/nest a table inside a div`. Awesome!

Comment: @A.Wolff This is my english... Sorry for my english :D

Comment: @TriSTaR No problem but a simple code/HTML example would have been easier to understand for sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `wrap()`:

```js
$( "table" ).wrap( "<div class='table-responsive'></div>" );
```

```css
.table-responsive{
  border:solid 1px red;
  }

table, td{
    border:solid 1px green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: YEAH,YEAH,YEAAAAAH.... that's exactly what I needed, thanks a lot :))

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @blonfu You are a good translator for sure... ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff ahahaha... :D

Comment: @A.Wolff not too much. I supposed the OP wants a div wrapping the table, is the way to do responsive tables in bootstrap. In spanish you can say above instead wrap and the people understand :)

Comment: @blonfu Ok for spanish, it makes sense. And ok for `table-responsive` and bootstrap, it even make more sense now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Prepend all spans to the element with the class ".table-responsive" (Check .prepend() documentation for more examples)

Read More Details [Click](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)

```js
$( "span" ).prependTo( ".table-responsive" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">Hello</div>
<span>I have something to say... </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are  trying to do it like this. Am i right

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table>
     .......
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: You can prepend a new class above table tag but you have to get it in a string first then prepend desired class above table.

Comment: <div class="desired-class table-responsive"> check the html now

Comment: Why would I use the html code and the class in it... I want a jquery means to do..

Comment: yes .... i am going to tell you how in jquery

Comment: $('.table-responsive').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("class",  "Appended text." + $(this).attr("class") );
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.table-responsive').each(function() { $(this).attr("class", "Appended text." + $(this).attr("class") ); }); –
```

Comment: Mind to elaborate your code?